# Is there a JavaScript function to serialize and unserialize arrays like PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm making a PHP model to store a serialized array in a database. The array is then accessed via AJAX through an HTTP request.

Is there a JavaScript function to serialize and unserialize arrays like PHP?

EDIT: This is the php function http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean by "sterilize".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterilization_%28surgical_procedure%29? :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the (almost an year :) ) late response, but i just saw this.

Since i can only place one link, i will give you this one: http://phpjs.org/functions/index

Search for "**serialize**" and "**unserialize**" and you'll find them. I had to send serialized data to the server, and PHP works perfectly with the results of these functions.

Be sure to also take a look at the dependencies and get those functions as well.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You meant “serialize”?  jQuery’s `$.ajax` & `$.json` methods would automatically serialize JavaScript objects for you, and in modern browsers you can use `JSON.stringify` directly.

Comment: There is also a json library provided by Douglas Crockford at http://www.json.org/js.html